# retrieve data from firebase using getUid() in a alertDialog box

Tags: android

Want to retrieve username and its contact number from the firebase database. I tried doing it but in the logcat it throws an Null Pointer

> Logcat:-
>     Process: com.example.bhavya.epark, PID: 27351
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.bhavya.epark.userreg.getName()' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.bhavya.epark.MapSelect$1$1.onDataChange(MapSelect.java:51)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzap.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:75)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzca.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:63)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzcd$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.3:55)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

MapSelect.java

```
          mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                udetail = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference databaseReference = udetail.getReference(mAuth.getUid());
                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        userreg userprofile = dataSnapshot.getValue(userreg.class);
                        alertDialog1.setMessage("Name is:" + userprofile.getName());
                        alertDialog1.setMessage("Your Contact No:" + userprofile.getPnum());
                        alertDialog1.setMessage("Your Vehicle No is:" + userprofile.getVeclno());
                        alertDialog1.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapSelect.this,databaseError.getCode(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

userreg.java

package com.example.bhavya.epark;

public class userreg {
    public String name,mailid,pnum,veclno;

```
public userreg(){

}


public userreg(String name,String mailid,String pnum,String veclno){
    this.name=name;
    this.mailid=mailid;
    this.pnum=pnum;
    this.veclno=veclno;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getMailid() {
    return mailid;
}

public void setMailid(String mailid) {
    this.mailid = mailid;
}

public String getPnum() {
    return pnum;
}

public void setPnum(String pnum) {
    this.pnum = pnum;
}

public String getVeclno() {
    return veclno;
}

public void setVeclno(String veclno) {
    this.veclno = veclno;
}
```

}

Database Strucure:-

Image reference
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/owWJr.jpg

Comment: Post your database structure and userreg class too

Comment: You database image link is not clickable

Comment: The link is now clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pointing towards a wrong database reference. Your database has a node named *Users* but your code doesn't have this.

Instead of

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = udetail.getReference(mAuth.getUid());
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    userreg userprofile = dataSnapshot.getValue(userreg.class);
                    alertDialog1.setMessage("Name is:" + userprofile.getName());
                    alertDialog1.setMessage("Your Contact No:" + userprofile.getPnum());
                    alertDialog1.setMessage("Your Vehicle No is:" + userprofile.getVeclno());
                    alertDialog1.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(MapSelect.this,databaseError.getCode(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Use

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = udetail.getReference().child("Users");

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        userreg userprofile = messageSnapshot.getValue(userreg.class);
        Log.v("info",String.valueOf(userprofile));
    }
        //Do whatever you like to do with your data here
}


@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MapSelect.this,databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
});
```

Comment: I have made the suggested changes and It is not throwing any null pointer exception now, but I cannot retrieve the data and display it in a alertdialog box. Can please help me out with it.

Comment: Thanks a ton! It is working fine now. the userprofile was out of scope.!!